# Setting the div margins, and set display: inline-block

Tags: html, css

I have three `div` elements with the following id's `#body`, `#firstDiv` and `#secondDiv`.

I'm trying to set `top: 0` and `left: 0` on `#body`, but for some reasons its giving me around 5 pixels each. At first I thought it was the margins, after I set the margins to 0 pixels, it's still showing around 5 pixels of space all around.

Also, I'm trying to get the `#firstDiv` and `#secondDiv` to be side by side, instead of one on top of each other. I set `display: inline-block`, but that didn't change anything.

What am I doing wrong?

```
#body {
    background-color:black;
    top: 0px;
    left: 0px;
    margin: 0px;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
}

#firstDiv {
    background-color:red;
    display: inline-block;
    width: 50%;
    height: 50%;
}

#secondDiv {
    background-color:green;
    display: inline-block;
    width: 50%;
    height: 50%;
}
```

```
<div id = 'body'>

    <div id = 'firstDiv'> firstDiv </div>
    <div id = 'secondDiv'> secondDiv </div>

</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The margin is on the `body` element itself, not the `#body` div.

`left: 0` and `right: 0` don't affect statically positioned elements, if you would like to absolutely position these elements use `position: absolute;`, but it looks like you're just having a problem with the body's margins.

And, when you set an element to `display: inline-block` white space between tags is rendered as a single white-space character, set `font-size: 0` on the parent and `font-size: 1rem` on all the children.

```
body {
    margin: 0;
}

#body {
    background-color:black;
    height: 100%;
    font-size: 0;
}

#body > * {
    font-size: 1rem;
    display: inline-block;
    vertical-align: top;
}
```

```css
body {
    margin: 0;
}

#body {
    background-color:black;
    height: 100%;
    font-size: 0;
}

#body > * {
    font-size: 1rem;
    display: inline-block;
    vertical-align: top;
}

#firstDiv {
    background-color:red;
    width: 50%;
    height: 50%;
}

#secondDiv {
    background-color:green;
    width: 50%;
    height: 50%;
}
```

```html
<div id = 'body'>

    <div id = 'firstDiv'> firstDiv </div>
    <div id = 'secondDiv'> secondDiv </div>

</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

1. `left` and `right` don't have any result for elements with static position.
2. Add `padding: 0;` and `margin: 0;` to your `html` and `body`.
3. Your divs go one under another, because they don't fit. Point 2 should fix it.

Comment: It's actually not a body element. It's a div element with an id called #body.